# DataTables using PHP with MySQL: How to modify the mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

So I'm trying to populate a html table using a table in my database. Lets call it 'business' and one of the columns is called 'id'.
I am trying to use WHERE. I
For example something like..

```
SELECT * all FROM business WHERE id=4.
```

Do I need to modify $sWhere?

Here is the code that I am using for server side processing.

```
/*
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
 * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine, 2012 - Chris Wright
 * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */
/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * Easy set variables
 */

/* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
$aColumns = array('bus_num', 'bus_phone', 'category_name', 'bus_status');

/* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
$sIndexColumn = "id";

/* DB table to use */
$sTable = "business";

/* Database connection information */
$gaSql['user']       = "dev";
$gaSql['password']   = "dev";
$gaSql['db']         = "dev";
$gaSql['server']     = "localhost";

/* REMOVE THIS LINE (it just includes my SQL connection user/pass) */
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dev', 'dev');

if (!$db){
    die ("Could not connect to database" . mysql_error());
    exit();
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dev', $db);

if(!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use:' . mysql_error());
}


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

/*
 * Local functions
 */
function fatal_error ( $sErrorMessage = '' )
{
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] .' 500 Internal Server Error' );
    die( $sErrorMessage );
}


/*
 * MySQL connection
 */
if ( ! $gaSql['link'] = mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not open connection to server' );
}

if ( ! mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) )
{
    fatal_error( 'Could not select database ' );
}


/*
 * Paging
 */
$sLimit = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
{
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".intval( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        intval( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
}


/*
 * Ordering
 */
$sOrder = "";
if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
{
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".($_GET['sSortDir_'.$i]==='asc' ? 'asc' : 'desc') .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
}


/*
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
$sWhere = "";
if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
        }
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
}

/* Individual column filtering */
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


/*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit 
";
$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );

/* Data set length after filtering */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
";
$rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
$iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

/* Total data set length */
$sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
";
$rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or fatal_error( 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_errno() );
$aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
$iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);

while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $output );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: I solved this by passing a GET variable to $sWhere

Comment: Hi i am also using above code .. is your search working properly ? ..means when u search it shows you Id=4 record search only ? .. as in my search its showing me other RECORD too after search .. can you please paste full code here ?

Comment: i have asked question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015124/datatables-searching-at-server-side-php-mysql

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
* Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */

//$sWhere = "";

if ( isset($_GET['sSearch']) && $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
{
$sWhere = "WHERE id='4' AND (";
for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
{
    if ( isset($_GET['bSearchable_'.$i]) && $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
}
$sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
$sWhere .= ')';
} else {
$sWhere = "WHERE id = '4' ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> [DataTables](http://datatables.net/index) is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. It is a
>   highly flexible tool, based upon the foundations of progressive
>   enhancement, which will add advanced interaction controls to any HTML
>   table.

you might want to use:

> Server-side processing | PHP with MySQL This script serves as the
>   basis for the testing and development that happens with DataTables, so
>   it is always right up to date, and will always implement all of the
>   features that are supported in DataTables with server-side processing
>   (with the exception of regex filtering - for database access speed
>   reasons).
>
> To use the code on your own server, simply change the $aColumns array
>   to list the columns you wish to include from your database, set
>   $sIndexColumn to a column which is indexed (for speed), $sTable to the
>   table name, and finally fill in your database connection parameters to
>   $gaSql. Please note that this script uses json_encode which requires
>   PHP 5.2 or newer. For a version of this script which is compatible
>   with older versions please see the PHP 4 compatible

http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql

Comment: I got this php part to partly work, all the data is presented, with my index.php, but the filtering by column, pagination, and number of entries per page is not working. my index.php looks like [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html) but the `tfoot` and `theader` are static and the tbody is filled by what is returned by the db. any idea?