# datatables + connecting to a db + getting data but some features not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am new to datatables and like it and want to learn more.

My current issue is with communicating with the database. I can get all the data but some of the features are not wroking(e.g. pagination, the entries per page, the search, the search per column).

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/) that is fairly basic.
I have included the `tbody` tag with 2 rows, for testing, of data which the search and column search works for. My difficulty is getting it to work with database data.

So in my example where I connect to a db,it is slightly different from the above fiddle. It has a `index3.php` file, which points to a `employee-grid-data3.php` file

**Below Code in my index.php that points at `employee-grid-data3.php` for connectin to db**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataTable = $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax":{
                url :"employee-grid-data3.php", // json datasource
                type: "post",  // method  , by default get
                error: function(){  // error handling
                    $(".employee-grid-error").html("");
                    $("#employee-grid").append('<tbody class="employee-grid-error"><tr><th colspan="3">No data found in the server -- startagain1-index3.php </th></tr></tbody>');
                    $("#employee-grid_processing").css("display","none");

                }
            }
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

my `employee-grid-data3.php` looks exactly like this code [here](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql), which I got from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20285403/2392358).

Now the data loads from the database but the pagination, the entries per page, the search, the search per column does not seem to comunicate with the db.

Based on what I have provided is there a way to advise me how I can get it working?

For instance, does it have to do with this snippet of code below from `employee-grid-data3.php`, in that what I am returning is not completely aligned with what I am expecting to receive.

```
/*
 * Output
 */
$output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
);
```

**edit1**
useful links:
https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1 - after looking at the faq was led here

Comment: Do you see any kind of errors in your browser console?

Comment: no errors in console. the format of the data is like this(in network tab under [XHR](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1)) `{"sEcho":0,
"iTotalRecords":"999",
"iTotalDisplayRecords":"999",
"aaData":[["2015-10-06","427","60","137765","Samsung Korea","Samsung SM-G900I","$39 Plan"],...` and all data is displayed on the 1 page even though it offers other pages.

Comment: https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html. Here is a link which explains data tables for php. Please go through the link and see what you are missing. It seems like more needs more stuff needs to be added to your code

Comment: tks for the link you provided, but that seems to be missing a `fata error` function. so don't think my code is missing anything. I did notice the following values not assigned any values, but presume this is meant to be? ` Line 62:     $sLimit = "";
 Line 73:     $sOrder = "";
 Line 89:             $sOrder = "";
 Line 100:     $sWhere = "";`

Comment: Are you including all the required jquery files Togo with it.

Comment: I am using data tables with jsp and I have to specially mention the above mentioned variables

Comment: Will post sample for you in an hour

Comment: Sorry did not get a chance away from my system right now

Comment: i am using the same libraries as i am in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sxqeauaz/) except for the css.