# datatables + serverside processing + search filtering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am following this tutorial:
http://coderexample.com/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

and here is the demo: 
http://coderexample.com/demo/datatable-demo-server-side-in-phpmysql-and-ajax/

If i search for `ou` in the search input i get `No matching records found` but what I would like returned is this row `Airi Satou` at least.

[this](https://github.com/coderexample/datatable_example/blob/master/demo1/employee-grid-data.php) is the code that i have to change, I think, as I have to do the search server side.

```
<?php
/* Database connection start */
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password1";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

/* Database connection end */


// storing  request (ie, get/post) global array to a variable  
$requestData= $_REQUEST;


$columns = array( 
// datatable column index  => database column name
    0 =>'employee_name', 
    1 => 'employee_salary',
    2=> 'employee_age'
);

// getting total number records without any search
$sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
$sql.=" FROM employee";
$query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
$totalData = mysqli_num_rows($query);
$totalFiltered = $totalData;  // when there is no search parameter then total number rows = total number filtered rows.


if( !empty($requestData['search']['value']) ) {
    // if there is a search parameter
    $sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
    $sql.=" FROM employee";
    $sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";    // $requestData['search']['value'] contains search parameter
    $sql.=" OR employee_salary LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $sql.=" OR employee_age LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");
    $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_rows($query); // when there is a search parameter then we have to modify total number filtered rows as per search result without limit in the query 

    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   "; // $requestData['order'][0]['column'] contains colmun index, $requestData['order'][0]['dir'] contains order such as asc/desc , $requestData['start'] contains start row number ,$requestData['length'] contains limit length.
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees"); // again run query with limit

} else {    

    $sql = "SELECT employee_name, employee_salary, employee_age ";
    $sql.=" FROM employee";
    $sql.=" ORDER BY ". $columns[$requestData['order'][0]['column']]."   ".$requestData['order'][0]['dir']."   LIMIT ".$requestData['start']." ,".$requestData['length']."   ";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("employee-grid-data.php: get employees");

}

$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {  // preparing an array
    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_name"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_salary"];
    $nestedData[] = $row["employee_age"];

    $data[] = $nestedData;
}



$json_data = array(
            "draw"            => intval( $requestData['draw'] ),   // for every request/draw by clientside , they send a number as a parameter, when they recieve a response/data they first check the draw number, so we are sending same number in draw. 
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ),  // total number of records
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ), // total number of records after searching, if there is no searching then totalFiltered = totalData
            "data"            => $data   // total data array
            );

echo json_encode($json_data);  // send data as json format

?>
```

Am I right to say that this is the code I have to change? 
If so, can anyone advise what I have to do? 
I understand this is alot to ask but would appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 $sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

will match search term then anything (due to wild card %)

as you want to match the search term in the middle of the name you need to add the wild card at the begging as well:

```
 $sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

Note this will disable the use of indexes on  `employee_name` which may or may not be a problem for you.

This is not the best search approach over all, you should not check all three fields, but ask the searcher which to use. After all age and salary could have some matching numbers.

a search for 27, could match age 27 or 27000 salary etc. And no one will have an *age* of **bob** so its pointless to do that search

Comment: Don't think indexes will matter in this instance but good point.
I am working towards a search per column but am haiving difficulty. question I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706424/datatables-connecting-to-a-db-getting-data-but-some-features-not-working). maybe you coul point me in the right direcition?
And I have to do the same for each column e.g. search `27` for this salary `162700` to show up.

Comment: @HattrickNZ i'm not sure from the comment if this question is now answered or not

Answer (score 1):

Your query need to be updated.

The following SQL statement selects all with a employee_name starting with "search field value":

```
   $sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

so, your query should be something like below, to get desired output, as it check whether a particular pattern is present in the employee_name.

```
   $sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

Comment: tks same as dagon above.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are constructing your Where clause, the fields you are searching must start with the search term. Change your where clauses to

```
$sql.=" WHERE employee_name LIKE '%".$requestData['search']['value']."%' ";
```

You are also open to SQL injection by doing what you are doing. You need to use parameterized queries to remove this vulnerability. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for information

Comment: tks same as dagon above. and tks for sql injection link